# How to fit entire path inside the svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

How can I make sure that the entire SVG will be visible inside the view box? I have an SVG with intrinsic size of 167x210 and a react component of this shape

```
export const SvgIcon: React.FC<SvgIconProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, strokeWidth, width = 24, height = 24, className, fill } = props;
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className={className}
      fill={fill}
      viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
      stroke="currentColor"
      strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    >
      {children}
    </svg>
  );
};
```

so as you can see I set by default width and height to 24 and vie box to be this same size - 0 0 24 24, but when I paste the icon path markup all I can see is a small subset of what I should see, it does not scale down it crops the path.

this is how I use it:

```
export const LogoDay: React.FC<LogoProops> = ({
  width,
  height,
  variant,
}) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon width={width} height={height}>
      <path
        d="M158 2H1.5V211H158C158 211 182 133.5 158 124C134 114.5 67.5 124 67.5 124V70C67.5 70 138 80.5 158 70C178 59.5 158 2 158 2Z"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-width="3"
      />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
};
```

I tried everything from this article https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ tried messing tiwh preserveAspectRatio but nothing seem to be working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The viewBox should be a reflection of the max X and Y coordinates of the path, so it can fit inside.

Only the height and width properties of the svg should be fed by the height and width props, and not the viewBox, which needs to be computed from the max X and Y of the path, and also passed as a prop:

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className={className}
      fill={fill}
      viewBox={viewBox}
      stroke="currentColor"
      strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    >
      {children}
</svg>
```

You would need to compute the max X and Y coordinates of the path so that your implementation be something like:

```js
export const LogoDay: React.FC<LogoProops> = ({
  width,
  height,
  variant,
}) => {
const path = "M158 2H1.5V211H158C158 211 182 133.5 158 124C134 114.5 67.5 124 67.5 124V70C67.5 70 138 80.5 158 70C178 59.5 158 2 158 2Z";
  return (
    <SvgIcon width={width} height={height} viewBox={calcViewBox(path)}>
      <path
        d={path}
        stroke="black"
        stroke-width="3"
      />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
};
```

Comment: hi @alp_graphieros thanks for the reply, and what would be the formula to calculate the path? :) I thought that I woulg create a smaller version in figma and tha perhaps it would be easier to expand it but the strokeWidth stays too wide

Comment: Could you provide more detail and maybe some code, as I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'calculating the path' (in your code the path is hardcoded) ?

Comment: I don't have more code but the context is that when I use this SVG inside the image tag or Next Image component the path scales nicely but I am unable to animate certain parts of it, I would like to be able to set width and height on the SvgIcon component above and have the SVG path scale like I was using it within the image but with a possibility to create interactions with certain parts of it

Comment: To enable user interactions on specific path segments, you need to create several path elements inside your SvgIcon. All together they would just appear as one path for the user, but you can attach individual events. I'm sorry if that's not the answer you are looking for, again this is very abstract without code to check out :)

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/dziekonskik/vseven/pull/1 it's just a starter but I want to make my portfolio/business website and I want to get creative with SVG and learn how it works in the process when you run the code you will notice the issue, basically, I would like to achieve the scaling effect provided by Image component but in the SvgIcon or logo component, to be able to play with it. Also if you could pass on some learning sources I would be very happy :) clearly i don't understand the mechanics of SVG